# Why do `&n` and `&n + 1` differ by `4` instead of `1`?

Tags: c++, memory

I would expect the values of  `&n` and `&n + 1` to be adjacent memory boxes, so their address should differ by `1`. However, every time I run these commands, I get addresses that differ by 4 (for example `0056F800` and `0056F804`). Why does this happen?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n = 3;
    cout << &n << endl;
    cout << &n + 1;
}
```

Comment: What is `n`?  A [mcve] would be helpful.

Comment: Hint: `sizeof(*n)`.

Comment: @Eljay I've added an example.

Comment: When you say "box", you're effectively saying "byte".  Do you believe integers are no larger than a single byte?  If they are larger, then they must be separated by more than one byte to avoid overlap.

Comment: Food for thought: If you make it 1, you have to choose between `int* + int*` not resulting in `int*` or ending up with some `int*` that points into the middle of an `int`. Both of those are really awkward.

Comment: @TomKarzes Oh so `&n` is the address of the first byte of `n`, but then `&n + 1` is the address after the last byte of `n`. Intuitive in a way, but counterintuitive in another.

Comment: @chris I'm sorry, I don't fully understand. What exactly is `int*`?

Comment: @TomKarzes Nevermind, I don't think my explanation is a good way of thinking about it. I would've thought that `&n + 2` is `&n` incremented by `5`, but I see it's actually incremented by `8`.

Comment: @Ovi When adding an integer to a pointer, the integer is multiplied by the size of the object the pointer points to.  The compiler performs this multiplication automatically.  So if you have `int *p;` and `int i;`, then when you do `p + i`, the actual pointer addition is `p + sizeof(*p)*i`, which in this case is `p + sizeof(int)*i`.

Comment: @TomKarzes Yup got it, thanks!

Comment: @Ovi, `int*` is a pointer to an `int`. In `int* + int*`, it's meant as a stand-in for any value of that type since my statement was just focusing on types.

Comment: @chris It seems to me that the addresses of `int` variables are always numbers divisible by `4`. Are you saying that if you add two addresses of ints, then you get an address that is a *feasible* address for another int (since the sum of two multiples of `4` is a multiple of `4`)? I tried adding two pointers in C++ btw and the debugger says that I can't add two pointers.

Comment: @Ovi, Oops, I did mean to add a number, not a second pointer. I guess that's what I'm saying though, put differently. If it's up to the programmer to remember to multiply by `sizeof(int)` every time they do pointer arithmetic, it would be easy to forget, producing a result that points to an unintended address (quite possibly partially through an existing `int` object). It's also rather rare to want anything except multiples of `sizeof(int)`, meaning that multiplication by `sizeof(int)` on almost every pointer artihmetic expression would end up as repetetive boilerplate.

Comment: @chris Oh I completely understand now, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pointer arithmetic creates a pointer to a specific *element* of an array (or equivalently, a single object which is treated as an array of size 1), so it effectively changes the value of the pointer by multiples of the element size.

On your system an `int` is apparently 4 bytes in size so by adding 1 to an `int *` it creates a pointer value 4 larger than the original value.